# ls -d not doing what I'm told it should

Tags: command-line, ls

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Straight machine, no dual boot or anything.

I am in `~/scratch`
I want a list of directories only.

```
tree -dL 1
```

Got it!

`man ls` says:

```
-d List directories only instead of their contents.
```

`info ls` says:

```
-d List just the names of directories...
```

Clearly, this is not doing what I'm told it should.
What don't I understand?

Comment: Just a suggestion - you can use `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%f\n"` as well. And if you wanna avoid memorizing the command, allias it to something like `lsdirs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:  `ls -d */`
it will list the directories in the current directory

Answer (score 5):

`ls -d` will list directory entries without their contents, it is not used to show only the directory entries inside a directory.

An example will make you clear:

```
$ tree
.
├── egg
├── spam
└── test
    ├── new
    └── old


$ ls *
egg  spam

test:
new  old


$ ls -d *
egg  spam  test
```

As you can see `-d` just makes sure that the contents of directory `test` is not being shown.

As already shown in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/692154/216503), to show only the directory entries, you can use `*/`. The `/` after `*` ensures that only directories will be shown:

```
$ ls -d */
test/
```

This is analogous to:

```
$ for i in *; do [[ -d $i ]] && echo "$i"; done
test
```